# Importing a csv file, using string operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm making a program which requires me to create csv files with names that are generated by the script. Therefore I cannot open the csv file using

```
open("file.csv")
```

but I have to use a variable to get the name:

```
open("%s.csv" % x)
```

This, however gives me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.csv'
```

The files are automatically saved in the same folder as my script, and I have tested to make sure the variable works and gives the name of the file.

Comment: Your error means that x is an empty string.  Also you should pass `'w'` as second parameter to `open(...)` in order to create file, otherwise it is open for reading only.

Comment: Examine what `x` is immediately before you open the file. You'll find it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you have lots of file-name and you have stored them in List(allfileslist).

```
for name in allfileslist:

    name=name+".csv"

    f = open(name,"w+")

    f.close()
```